# Is there a better way to type check my search by keyword query

Tags: typescript

My query and queryStr types seem excessive, they work perfectly fine, Im just wondering if they could be simplified. The types are coming my product model(ProductDoc), could generics be used instead? I've tried a fews combination but none made sense, Please let me know if its better to use generics or if the current types are the best approach.

```
export class ApiFeatures {
  query: Query<
    (ProductDoc & { _id: Types.ObjectId })[],
    ProductDoc & { _id: Types.ObjectId },
    {},
    ProductDoc
  >;
  queryStr: ParsedQs;

  constructor(
    query: Query<
      (ProductDoc & { _id: Types.ObjectId })[],
      ProductDoc & { _id: Types.ObjectId },
      {},
      ProductDoc
    >,
    queryStr: ParsedQs
  ) {
    this.query = query;
    this.queryStr = queryStr;
  }

  search() {
    const keyword = this.queryStr.keyword
      ? {
          title: {
            $regex: this.queryStr?.keyword,
            $options: "i",
          },
        }
      : {};

    this.query = this.query.find({ ...keyword });
    return this;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the implementation of the `Query<>` type it's not possible to fully answer this question, but with regards to whether you should use a generic - the `Query<>` type is *already* a generic. You can, however, simplify your `ProductDoc & { _id: Types.ObjectId }` in the places where it is used by creating a new type that extends ProductDoc with the `_id` field.

```js
interface ProductDocWithId extends ProductDoc {
  _id: Types.ObjectId;
}

export class ApiFeatures {
  query: Query<ProductDocWithId[], ProductDocWithId, {}, ProductDoc>;
  queryStr: ParsedQs;

  // implementation
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the implementation of Query<> but you advice on simplifying ProductDoc makes sense.